# {0[Jack]:d} in Python .format(), What is the '0' indicate here?

Tags: python, format, string-formatting

```
table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 8637678}

print('Jack: {[Jack]:d}'.format(table))  

print('Jack: {0[Jack]:d} {0[Jack]:d}'.format(table))

#print('Jack: {[Jack]:d} {[Jack]:d}'.format(table))  
==> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What is the 0 indicate in `{0[Jack]:d}` and why do the last print statement raise index error?

Resource: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

Comment: the zero indicates the index from which to look for the data in.  The last print statement raises an error because if you don't indicate the index (such as the second example), then the index is assumed to increment automatically. Thus the third example is looking for two values to replace, but you only provided one table.

Answer (score 0):

{0[jack]:20d}, {0[jack]:10f}, [0[jack]:20e}

0 is replacement index. It is easier to be understand in the last example in the same charpter ( 7.1.2. The String format() Method). In this case, only one item can be changed. So, the index is 0.

d is digi, for int;
f for float, 6 decimal places;
e for Scientific notation, 1.2e−4=0.00012

20, or 10... :   20 (or 10) characters string length in your output.